# Redux combineReducer and createStore, how to pass initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

### Problem :

`Error: No Matching "@@redux/INITj.p.b.v.m.c" - action type`

The first stack frame references the first imported reducer, `cart_reducer`, 2 frames further is `combineReducers`

I believe this error is related to Redux failing to get initial state.

### What I'm trying to do :

Convert an ecommerce page from useReducer / contextAPI to Redux. There are 3 reducers each with their own initial state. I am trying to combine these reducers and pass them into `createStore()`. I believe my current setup is mostly correct, I just cant figure out how to pass the [preloadedState] into the `createStore()`

From the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore). I think the answer is here but I am having trouble understanding the statement.

> If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import cart_reducer from './cart_reducer';
import products_reducer from './products_reducer';
import filter_reducer from './filter_reducer';

const root_reducer = combineReducers({
  cartReducer: cart_reducer,
  productsReducer: products_reducer,
  filterReducer: filter_reducer,
});

const store= createStore(
  root_reducer,
  // pass initial states here... but how?
  );
```

`state` is then passed to the `Provider`

```
import store from './reducers/root_reducer';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}> // here
      <AuthWrapper>
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/'>
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/about'>
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/cart'>
              <Cart />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/products'>
              <Products />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/products/:id'>
              <SingleProduct />
            </Route>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/checkout'>
              <Checkout />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route exact path='*'>
              <Error />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </AuthWrapper>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Here is one of my reducers :

```
import {
  ADD_TO_CART,
  CLEAR_CART,
  COUNT_CART_TOTALS,
  REMOVE_CART_ITEM,
  TOGGLE_CART_ITEM_AMOUNT,
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  cart: [],
  // cart: getLocalStorage(),
  total_items: 0,
  total_amount: 0,
  shipping_fee: 534,
};

function cart_reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART: {
      const { id, color, amount, product } = action.payload;
      const tempItem = state.cart.find((i) => i.id === id + color);
      if (tempItem) {
        const tempCart = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
          if (cartItem.id === id + color) {
            let newAmount = cartItem.amount + amount;
            if (newAmount > cartItem.max) {
              newAmount = cartItem.max;
...ect
...ect

export default cart_reducer;
```

For saksh73

In a component

```
<button
        type='button'
        className='remove-btn'
        onClick={() => dispatch(removeItem(id))}
      >
```

In actions.js

```
const REMOVE_CART_ITEM = 'REMOVE_CART_ITEM';

export const removeItem = (id) => {
  return { type: REMOVE_CART_ITEM, payload: id };
};
```

In cart_reducer

```
case REMOVE_CART_ITEM: {
      const newCart = state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [...newCart],
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is correct. For the initial state you can have the initial state of each reducer in their respective initial state.

Your action must return an object if you are not using any middleware. If you want to use any middleware i.e redux thunk, redux saga then you must pass the second argument in `createStore`.

Here is an example:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import signUp from "./signUp";
import login from "./login";
import user from "./user";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  signUp,
  login,
  user,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));

export default store;
```

action example:

```
export function logIn(email, password) {
        dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
          payload: {
            email: email,
            password: password
          }
        });
  };
```

Comment: There must be something else wrong. I still have the error. My actions are returning objects, and I'm not using any middleware (yet)

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: can you please share one of your actions?

Comment: `Error: No Matching "@@redux/INITn.d.1.v.1" - action type` That string after INIT changes every time. Here is a small action `case CLEAR_CART: return {...state,cart: [], }; ` Edit: im so sorry about the formatting

Comment: Please share a full function where you are dispatching an action and from where you are calling that function using.

Comment: this is something that you want to do in your reducer when this action is dispatched...but i think you forgot to dispatch an action.

Comment: added an action example to the code. you have to call a function and dispatch an action from there in order to make changes in you reducer state.

Comment: I added the info you asked for to the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231532/discussion-between-saksh73-and-clinzy25).

Answer (score 0):

The doc just mean you need to pass initial state for each child reducer with the same key accordingly.

```
const store= createStore(
  root_reducer,
  // pass initial states with the same key 
  {
    cartReducer: cart_reducer_state,
    productsReducer: products_reducer_state,
    filterReducer: filter_reducer_state
  }
);
```